# How can I extract the Author of a PowerPoint in C#?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I apologize if there is a super simple answer, but I am really struggling trying to get the document properties of a PowerPoint file using C#.

Basically I want to be able to select a document, load it in to a PowerPoint Object and get the properties and do other things, but I am crashing at the first try. Has anyone managed to extract a simple property from a PowerPoint file using C#?

Thanks

Matthew Hardman

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-document-properties?view=vs-2017

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one bud, I tried the code as instructed, but get the following error

"System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2DF8D04D-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002"

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that I am using the PowerPoint object model, the document referred to earlier only made mention to Excel and Word.

Comment: This is the code I used
"
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;

properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties) _pptOpenFile.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

_authorName = properties["Author"].Value;
"